# How to add templates to java classes for existing projects in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using eclipse - Juno, I have a big java project, now to each and every class in that project I have to add a templete at starting of the class (kind of info like owner etc). I have to neglect property files, xml's, sql's etc kind of files in the project.
Is there any way to add a templete to an existing project. If i open each and every class manually and make these changes, it may take a week.
Plz help with answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Eclipse Copyright Generator

http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipsecopyrigh/

Comment: I have forked this project and there is a new version on GitHub: https://jmini.github.io/Eclipse-Copyright-Generator/

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this [Copyright Wizard](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/copyright-wizard?mpc=true&mpc_state=) plugin. Search in the eclipse market place. There is a [guide](http://www.wdev91.com/?p=cpw_ug) which will help you on this.